# Multiple Console Errors Logged for JavaScript/jQuery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, typeerror, failed-to-load-viewstate

Hi I am having a series of issues with my JavaScript/jQuery code! And even though I browsed through a list of similar questions, I can't find any answers that fits my problem.

These are the issues logged to the Google Chrome developer console:

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
- Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
- jQuery.Deferred exception: Failed to construct 'Document': Please use
  the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a
  function. TypeError: Failed to construct 'Document': Please use the
  'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a
  function.
     at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:29999)
     at k (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:30313)
  undefined
- Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Document': Please use the
  'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a
  function.
     at j (jquery.min.js:2)
     at k (jquery.min.js:2)

Thanks so much for your help!

Here's my JavaScript Code:

```
$(Document).ready(function() {

  var quote;

  function getNewQuote() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/',
      jsonp: 'jsonp',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        method: 'getQuote',
        lang: 'en',
        format: 'jsonp'
      },
      success: function(response) {
        quote = response.quoteText;
        $('#quote').text(response.quoteText);
        if (response.quoteAuthor) {
          $('#author').text('said by ' + response.quoteAuthor);
        } else {
          $('#author').text('- unkown');
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

view CodePen here: https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/KZqNdr/

[image: Screen-shot of the Google Chrome Developer Console Log]

Comment: Probably want to lowercase "Document" to "document"

Comment: @abney317, that is a correct catch! But the console is still logging the same errors....and this is crazy, because I have another project with jQuery/JavaScript, and it gives no such issues!

Comment: I see you changed `Document` to `document`.  But the message is actually telling you that your server was found, but the resource wasn't found on that server (that is what a 404 error is).  Please check your URL link: `http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/`... this represents a directory, and not a file.  You should have something like `http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/afilename.php`

Comment: @Sablefoste, hi, that 404 error is no longer showing in my Google Chrome developer console

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
$(Document).ready(function() {...});
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {...});
```

Comment: Did you add onClick events for buttons to make API calls?

Comment: no I haven't added that as yet, shouldn't the code work overall even before I add the buttons? Or not?

Comment: Because I didn't see any error from CodePen after this correction, wondering if any other codes missing.

Comment: you "didn't see any error from CodePen after this correction?" Where? I also just uploaded a screen-shot of all the failures logged to the Google Chrome Developer Console.

Comment: I mean that there's no error after correcting 'Document' to 'document' in the CodePen console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162456/discussion-between-t-liu-and-codebwoy).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry! I should have also included my `html` code in my question. I found that in my `html` sheet's `<head></head>` tags, I had this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="Random Quote Machine.css">`. This was a carry over from my text editor, wherein I needed that link for file communicae. I also tested this solution by inserting such a line of code into the `html` sheet of another of my CodePen projects that includes JavaScript and jQuery, and then checked the Google Chrome developer and it gave the same error: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()**. I am so happy!:D